# Rails Controller Processing as */* (star slash star) rather than JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am sending http post with JSON data from an iphone app to a Rails app. I am sending the password reset email to devises' password controller. I've set my header for content-type as application/json.

The server log says:

```
Started POST "/users/password" for 192.168.0.11 at 2013-05-13 20:04:27 -0700
Processing by PasswordsController#create as */*
```

What does it mean when it says "star slash star"? How do I make it process as Json?

```
*/*
```

Comment: can you try with `accept` header, or `/users/password.json`?

Comment: ok so if used the link /users/password.json the controller will say processing as JSON. So does */* means Rails doesn't know how to process it or something? setting the content-type in the header is not enough?

Comment: content-type is the MIME of the request. While accept are the accepted response formats. I don't know exactly how Rails handles it, did it work with accept or with .json in URL? you tried with each one?

Comment: Did u try specifying :format=>"JSON" in routes to get it as JSON

Comment: What are your routes?